# Is the Night King capable of going across the sea?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We have already seen The Night King's mystical powers in *Game Of Thrones*. He can create ice spears (such as the one he used to kill *Viserion*) and freeze a sword until it shatters.

Can he freeze a lake or even a sea to rule over the islands and kill the humans on it?

I know this thought is pretty vague but one could not limit the ambitions of the Night King.

Comment: The wights travel under the frozen lake to retrieve Viserion's corpse, so it's possible that they wouldn't need any special means to cross the sea. They could just walk.

Comment: @DKu - being in the dry, frozen air is going to have a vastly different impact on dead flesh than being submerged in water.  I think walking any distance under water is going to pretty much cause a wight to fall apart.  Since the Night King wanted the dragon badly enough, I think he was fine on sacrificing any number of them to take the chains down and attach them to the dragon corpse, but that probably would not work as well if you needed them to fight after such a hike.  Which would explain why they stop at water.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we think logically, he could have come around the wall if he could freeze the sea (shown in red).

[image]

I think, with the help of the dragon he captured, he can fly across the ocean.

Answer (score 9):

No, he can't freeze a lake. In the lead-up to killing Viserion, he and his army had to wait patiently for the lake to freeze naturally before they could attack Jon Snow and friends. Had he been able to freeze the lake himself, he likely would have done so, and would've killed everyone on the island before the dragons ever showed up.

Comment: It is entirely possible that the Night King did not freeze the lake on purpose, as he was waiting for the dragons to show up. He would gain very little by massacring the few people on that island, but he gains the means to cross the wall by waiting for the dragon. Furthermore, we have previously seen water freeze instantly before the White Walkers.

Comment: He gains fresh, combat-capable corpses for his army. Besides, does he have any reason to assume that if he waits long enough to kill them, a dragon will show up for him to take?

Comment: Considering that the Night King is able to see and mark Bran as he uses greensight, it is also possible that the Night King is tapped into this power and was fully aware that Daenerys was on the way with her dragons.

Comment: what makes you say the night king isn't responsible for the extreme cold? the time to freeze may still be 'natural' but that doesn't mean the cold itself is.

Comment: @DKu - I don't think knowing where Bran is necessarily means he can basically warg into Bran or borrow his powers.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I'm not saying he wargs into Bran. I'm saying he also may be tapped into greensight. The power is derived from the Children, not Bran.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet This isn't true. Jojen uses greensight, Rickon appears to use greensight, and in the books there are many others such as the Warlocks of Qarth and the Red Priests. The Three-Eyed Raven is special as he seemingly has total control of the power, which appears to come from the weirwood tree, which comes from the Children. The previous Three-Eyed Raven was even straight chillin' with some Children.

Comment: Even simpler: he clearly could have just sniped them all with some ice javelins. He must not have for a particular reason; it was to his advantage to bide his time.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Almost nothing you said is accurate. Maester Luwin tells Bran about the greenseers of the children in book 1: "Their gods were the gods of the forest... Their wise men were called greenseers, and carved strange faces in the weirwoods to keep watch on the woods." You can read more about it here: https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Greenseer

Comment: @PoloHoleSet The quote says that the Children of the Forest were the first greenseers. Luwin is talking about BEFORE the First Men arrived. The war started because the First Men started cutting down the heart trees as soon as they arrived. The heart trees and the greenseers both clearly precede the First Men. Please follow the link and read it, it summarizes it much better than I can with the limited comment space here.

Comment: I never said "the Children create greenseers." I also never said that the Night King IS a greenseer. I said that it's POSSIBLE he could be somehow tapped into that power. And it IS possible. You are trying very hard to refute things that I'm not saying while failing to refute the point I made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92847/discussion-between-poloholeset-and-dku).